# CSS transform ok in Chrome and Edge but ugly in Firefox

Tags: css, html, firefox, transform

I am using CSS transformations to zoom in and out in the browser, but it looks ugly in Firefox even though it looks good in Chrome and Edge!

Firefox: 
[image: firefox]

Edge: 
[image: edge]

Chrome: 
[image: chrome]

What can I do?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your grammar a little bit to make your question a little easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

1st check the console and if there any errors solve it.
also try out with

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() { 
  .class {
     property:value;
  }
}
```

or

```
 -moz-transform:
```

it may work

Answer (score 0):

Firefox does renders images as good as Chrome and Edge(thumbs up), so for now you can use a image of bigger dimensions and use CSS to fit to shrink into the container(DIV). Then you can use CSS transformations to give zooming effect.

Thanks.

Comment: I render divs & buttons, no images!